# Representation of Frey's curve.

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I read that Frey's curve is a semi-stable elliptic curve. What doe this mean ?
I can find two dimensional representations of $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ in Wikipedia. What does $y^2 = x(x-a)(x+b)$ look like if $a$ and $b$ are solutions to $FLT$ ?

Comment: Semistable is a condition on the severity of bad reduction at primes namely they can only be of multiplicative type, and an Elliptic curve is a complete 1-dimensional group variety (probably over the integers). Do you know what all of these mean? I notice you are asking a lot of questions about FLT, but your question on algebraic integers suggest that you should probably read a few books on number theory before attempting to understand the proof. It took thousands of mathematicians hundreds of years before if was finished. But then again, curiosity is how we all joined this field, so maybe

Comment: you should ask a more general question about the general structure of these objects, or even better, pick up a book on Elliptic curves or Algebraic Number Theory (Or maybe Abstract Algebra, hard to say without knowing your current knowledge)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please show me what $ y^2 = x(x-a)(x+b) $ looks like for different a and b ?

Comment: Well, since no $a, b$ exist, it is kinda hard to plot it geometrically. I mean over the complex numbers, it should look kinda like a donut, but just topologically. The proof itself requires understanding of the equation over things like the integers or finite fields, so it is kinda impossible, if not unproductive to think about what it looks like. It's an elliptic curve, it kinda just looks like other elliptic curves

Comment: Asking what the curve $E:y^2 = x(x-a)(x+b)$ "looks like" is not useful. As @Kamina said above, $E$ is a group variety; topologically, it's a torus. There's a huge amount of background about the subject that woudl be necessary to explain semistability, modularity, etc. (For a place to start, I'd recommend Silverman's book.)

Comment: The answer I was looking for is here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/434119/212507