# Elliptic curve, different forms of.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elliptic-functions, weierstrass-factorization

1. $y^2 = x^3 + mx + c$    An elliptic curve in the form defined in Wikipedia
2. $y^2 = x(x-A)(x+B) = x^3 +(B-A)x^2 + ABx$     Frey's curve
3. has no term in $x^2$, but $2$. does because from Fermat, $A=a^n$ not equal to $B=b^n$

Question: Is there a simple way to transform Frey's curve with given $A,B$ into form $1$.

(Has it got anything to do with Weierstrass ?)

Comment: in $(x+c)^3 + (B-A) (x+c)^2$  the $x^2$ terms cancel for $3c =  -(B-A)$

Comment: 7 questions and not even a single accepted answer? You must be really picky then, don't be surprised if people stop answering your questions.

Comment: There's a little check mark next to each answer. If you find that one of the answers to a question answers the question, you can click in that check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: The answer I was looking for is at:
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/434119/212507

Comment: Alex M. "7 questions and not even 1 accepted answer" sounds bad ...... until you realize_ I have only 1 answer to accept._