# The Weierstrass form of an elliptic curve in the Legendre family

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Given an elliptic curve 
\begin{equation}
y^2=x(x-1)(x- \lambda), \lambda \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{equation}
in the Legendre family, is there an explicit procedure (algorithm) to transform it into its Weierstrass form?

Edit: I made a mistake about the terminology, what I mean is $\mathbb{Z}$-minimal model.

Comment: Seriously ? $(x+a/3)^3 = x^3+x^2a+..$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transform into weierstrass-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433973/transform-into-weierstrass-form)

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I think I used the wrong terminology. What I mean is to transform such an elliptic curve (when $\lambda$ is not integral) to one with integral coefficients! Is it called Weierstrass model or integral model? (or minimal model?)

Comment: Your curve is $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$. Then $(y/c^3)^2=(x/c^2)^3+A(x/c^2)+B$ has integral coefficients for $c$ large enough. The minimal $c\in \Bbb{Z}$ gives a $\Bbb{Z}[2^{-1},3^{-1}]$-minimal model, the $\Bbb{Z}$-minimal model needs looking at the general Weierstrass equation, the algorithm is explained in Silverman.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}[2^{-1},3^{-1}]$-minimal model means that the valuation of the discriminant is $\ge 0$ and as small as possible for all $p\ne 2,3$ (compared to all the other models).

Comment: @reuns Thank you. I will take a look at Silverman's book.

Comment: [Tate's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%27s_algorithm) computes the minimal model of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$.